# What data is needed for an end to end docusign workflow process

Tags: docusignapi

I'm looking to understand what data is needed for API integration.

Do users have to have an account, does the user signature get associated to the users account?  What data needs to be sent when integrating via API (and with no docusign UI ideally).

I've looked at the API documentation but I'm yet to understand exactly what data would be needed.  Happy to provide more information if needed.  I would be wanting to avoid the user having to give a visual consent.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding:

> Do users have to have an account

The **sender** of a signing request (either the person themselves or the application on behalf of someone else) needs a paid account on DocuSign.

The **signer** or **signers** or additional recipients of the signing request do not need anytype of account (nor any signup) with DocuSign.

> does the user signature get associated to the users account?

The signer's signature is associated with the signer. When someone signs their second signing request, their preferred signing style is often saved from the prior time. Exceptions: embedded signing works slightly differently; people who sign via a mobile device usually sign their signature each time; the **sender** can require the **signer** to re-do their signature style.

> What data needs to be sent when integrating via API

At a minimum:

1. The document(s) that need to be signed. They can be in any of many different formats.
2. The name and email or sms information for the signer(s)
3. The location(s) on the page(s) of where the signer(s) should sign. There are multiple ways to specify the `Sign Here` tab locations.

> (and with no docusign UI ideally).

Agreed! The best integrations with DocuSign often don't show any part of the DocuSign UI to the sender of the agreements.

Comment: I've looked at some examples and their documentation, it looks like the recipient will have to allow consent - is it possible to have a client credential authentication method with a user scoped token in response so that the recipient doesn't have to click consent?  thanks

Comment: Signing recipients do not give oauth consent. Only the sender gives consent to the application to represent them

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an [integration](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/build-integration/) where users sign a document.
All you need is a [document](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/documents/), can be PDF, Word, HTML, text, even images.
Then you start building your integration in the [developer environment](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/account/), where you can create yourself the necessary [configuration information](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/choose/) (IK (clientID), clientSecret etc.)

The end user using your integration does not have to have a DocuSign account, but before you can [go live](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/go-live/), you need to have a paid production account.

Your integration should collect, at a minimum, a name and email address (or phone number if you rather [use SMS](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/sms-delivery/) instead of email) for the [signer](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/recipients/).

Lastly, you will have to decide where on the document(s) the user has to sign or use other [tabs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/) such as date signed, initials etc

**START HERE - use quickstart** and see [how it works in action](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/), get working code in one of eight coding languages and see for yourself.